# How can I extract the name of a <tr> tag by using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Given the following html document, how can I extract the string "CLN8"?

```
<tr data-table-chart-alt-symbol="CLN8" data-table-chart-symbol="@CL.1">
<td class="first text" data-field="symbol"><a href="//www.cnbc.com/quotes/?symbol=%40CL.1">OIL</a></td>
<td data-field="last"></td>
<td class="arrow" data-field="change_arrow"><div class="icon unch">---</div></td>
<td data-field="change"></td>
<td data-field="change_pct"></td>
<td data-field="volume"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: is `name` an attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup.find`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(html, 'html.parser').find('tr')['data-table-chart-alt-symbol']
```

Output:

```
'CLN8'
```